# Copy cell data to second sheet based on matching data

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-macros

I want to use data from a Google Form (Sheet 1) that is collecting in and out times and locations. I would like them in and out submission consolidated on a second sheet (Sheet 2) the end product. If email and date match place them in and out time stamp on a second sheet to be used for additional calculations and viewing. There are several examples out there and things that I have tried but nothing that I can find. This may not be possible in the current format if additional data is needed to filter it can be added. Thanks for the help in advance.

**Sheet 1**

```
        A                    B              C                     D
    Timestamp              Email        Going to               Out/In
1/29/2019 16:06:42    Bob@gmail.com      Locker                  Out
1/29/2019 16:06:58    Bob@gmail.com                              In
1/29/2019 16:13:32    Tom@gmail.com     Bathroom                 Out
1/29/2019 16:14:35    Jon@gmail.com     Bathroom                 Out
1/29/2019 16:13:48    Tom@gmail.com                              In
1/29/2019 16:20:00    Jon@gmail.com                              In
```

**Sheet 2**

```
 A               B                  C                          D
Email           Went to             Out                         In
Bob@gmail.com   Locker      1/29/2019 16:06:42      1/29/2019 16:10:58
Tom@gmail.com   Bathroom    1/29/2019 16:13:32      1/29/2019 16:23:48
Jon@gmail.com   Bathroom    1/29/2019 16:14:35      1/29/2019 16:20:00
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried combinations of Match or filter and can not get the output I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
={"Email", "Went to", "In", "Out"; 
 {QUERY('Sheet 1'!A2:D, 
  "select B, C, A where C is not null and not D contains 'In'", 0), 
  ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(QUERY('Sheet 1'!A2:D, 
  "select A where C is null and D contains 'In'", 0), 'Sheet 1'!A2:D, 1, 0))}}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it did exactly what I wanted to.